# I am not able to get the postid after sharing a post on facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

I know that publish_actions have been deprecated. I am using share dialog box to share the post from my android app to fb timeline of the users. A few days back, in the onsuccess I was able to fetch the postid. But now, it is returning null. I have not made any changes in the coding part. Is there any problem with the fb?

I am using user_posts permission to get postid of the person sharing the posts.

Also, is there any alternative to do so? My entire app is based on getting the postid.

Comment: important question: what for exactly do you need to get the post id?

Comment: No, there should be more more way to do that.

Comment: It looks like they JUST got rid of it, like this past Thursday or Friday.

The documentation no longer shows post_id in the response.  

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

:(